# No setBounds function for Leaflet imageOverlay

Tags: leaflet

I'm reading an imageOverlay URL from an ArcGIS webserver that uses the leaflet getBound() coordinates as part of the URL (we have large maps that are filtered for the current window 'extent'). Apologies for not including the actual path (I'm working with sensitive client data). Eg:

`http://myarcgiswebserver.com/MapServer/export/dpi=96&format=png32&bbox=27.119750976562504%2C-31.194007509998823%2C32.39044189453126%2C-29.692824739380754&size=1719%2C434`

[bbox] = current imageBounds

When dragging my map the imageOverlay url is updated correctly but my leaflet window is no longer aligned to the imageBound values that were set when first adding the imageOverlay which results in a skewed output (this is my assumption):

[image: image of skewed results when i drag my map]

The only workaround is to remove the existing imageOverlay and add a new one (which ruins the user experience as the map disappears then reappears each time the window is dragged or zoomed).

Am i approaching this problem incorrectly or would the introduction of a function to update the current imageBounds resolve this? Perhaps not a new function but the expansion of setUrl with additional parameters...?

Many thanks for any feedback...

Comment: How do you add your `imageOverlay` on your map? If I understand correctly, it does not move with the map, hence it is no longer aligned when user drags / zooms?

Comment: Hi, it does move with the map but I'm forcing a (URL) refresh after zoom or drag to ensure high quality imageOverlay (to fit the new map area). Unfortunately using setUrl results in misalignment. Alignment is correct only when removing the layer and adding a new imageOverlay

Comment: you might also consider "esri leaflet' L.esri.dynamicMapLayer http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/simple-dynamic-map-layer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ghybs pointed out, your use case might be better served by using the WMS 
interface of your ArcGIS server.

Anyway, you say

> The only workaround is to remove the existing imageOverlay and add a new one (which ruins the user experience as the map disappears then reappears each time the window is dragged or zoomed).

Well, that glitch is due to you probably doing something like:

- Remove old overlay
- Add new overlay
- Wait until the image is received from the network
- Wait one frame so the new overlay is shown

and instead you should be doing something like:

- Add new overlay
- Wait until the image is received from the network
- Remove old overlay
- Wait one frame so the new overlay is shown

The problem is just the async wait and the possible race conditions there, but should be easy to hack together, e.g.:

```
var activeOverlay = null;
var overlayInRequest = null;

map.on('moveend zoomend', {

    // If we are already requesting a new overlay, ignore it.
    // This might need some additional debouncing logic to prevent
    // lots of concurrent requests
    if (overlayInRequest) {
        overlayInRequest.off('load', showOverlay);
    }

    overlayInRequest = L.imageOverlay( computeUrl( map.getBounds() ), myOverlayOptions );
    overlayInRequest.on('load', showOverlay);
});

function showOverlay(ev) {
    activeOverlay.remove();
    activeOverlay = overlayInRequest;
    activeOverlay.addTo(map);
    overlayInRequest = undefined;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, seeing as we're using ARCGIS enterprise edition i'll try push for WMS rather than a workaround. Probably more sustainable. Many thanks for you inputs and feedback!

Answer (score 1):

If you use an [`ImageOverlay`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#imageoverlay) but change its `url` dynamically, with a new image that reflects a new bounding box, then indeed that is the reason for the behaviour you describe: you display an image that has been generated using a new `bbox`, but positioned in the initial `bbox`, since the image overlay remains at the same geographical position on the map.

Instead, it sounds to me that you should use a [`TileLayer.WMS`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#tilelayer-wms).

It would automatically manage the bounding box update for you. You may need to find the correct options to fit your service provider required URL syntax, though.

Example: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/yel/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Let me point out that there is a [WMS Leaflet tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html) which will probably be useful for this.